# Capacity Property in C# Arraylist

Tags: c#

I was going through the properties of Arraylist in C#. What I did was:

```
ArrayList listInt = new ArrayList();
listInt.Add(9);
listInt.Add(10);
listInt.Add(11);
Console.WriteLine($"Capacity Before: {listInt.Capacity}");
```

The output came as 4, which is fine.
Next I tried AddRange() property:

```
ArrayList list2 = new ArrayList();
list2.Add("SAM");
list2.Add("MAN");
list2.Add("TAN");
listInt.AddRange(list2);
Console.WriteLine($"Capacity After: {listInt.Capacity}");
```

The output came as 8.

**Output**

[image: a]

How the capacity of my ArrayList became 8?

Comment: No one should really be using the `ArrayList` class these days.  It was included in .NET 1.0 and C# 1.0 to provide dynamic array functionality. With .NET 2.0 and C# 2.0 came generics and the `List<T>` class. That basically made the `ArrayList` obsolete.  An `ArrayList` is basically equivalent to a `List<object>` but if you specifically want to store `int` values or `string` objects then you should be using a `List<int>` or a `List<string>`. It's particularly important with value types like `int`. `List<T>.Capacity` works the same way as `ArrayList.Capacity` as described in the answer below.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you added 3 more elements to the list...

[`Capacity`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) is the size of the internal array... It starts at 0 then defaults to 4 on first single add. It then goes up by a factor of 2 when it needs more capacity.. This keeps the memory copying at a minimum (at the cost of a small bit of memory).

**Note** : Don't confuse `Capacity` with [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx) though, they are different things

You add 3 elements to your array

```
ArrayList listInt = new ArrayList(); // capacity = 0 
listInt.Add(9);                      // capacity = 4
listInt.Add(10);                     // capacity = 4
listInt.Add(11);                     // capacity = 4
```

So when you add your first element to the list, internally `Add` calls `EnsureCapacity`. Which looks like this ([Full Source Here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/eb66b6616c6fd4ef.html))

```
private const int _defaultCapacity = 4;

...
private void EnsureCapacity(int min)
{
   if (_items.Length < min)
   {
      int newCapacity = _items.Length == 0 ? _defaultCapacity : _items.Length * 2;
      ...
   }
}
```

Take note of `_items.Length * 2` ...

```
listInt.AddRange(list2);             // capacity = 8
```

You may only have had 3 elements in your list, However the capacity was 4. Now you add 3 more elements, its got no other choice then multiply the capacity by 2

---

[List.Capacity Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y52x03h2(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets or sets the total number of elements the internal data structure
>   can hold without resizing.

[List.Count Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/27b47ht3(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Gets the number of elements contained in the List.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was satisfactory.